# PrivateRouter component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm using a private router function component and I want to convert it into a class component.

My aim is to access Home with all its params with this route:

```
<PrivateRouteComponent path="/home" component={Home} />
```

and here's my class component:

```
class PrivateRouteComponent extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        let renderView = (this.props) => ( // <-- Shows an error for this
        FakeServer.isUserAuthenticated() == true // Dummy mockup server
            ? <Component {...this.props} />
            : <Redirect to='/login' />
        )
        return (
            <Route {...rest} render={renderView} />
        )
    }

}
```

I see an error for the line renderView definition line, saying:

```
 Parsing error: Invalid left-hand side in arrow function parameters
```

Comment: You do not need `this.props` as an argument in the renderView function. this.props can be used as it is inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved the problem by adding mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps functions and keeping render simpler...

```
class PrivateRouteComponent extends Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

}

componentDidMount() {
    let userObj = FakeServer.getAuthenticatedUser()
    this.props.getUserByUsername(userObj.user.username) // Mapped by connect()
}

render() {
    return (
        this.props.loading ? 'Loading in router' :
        <Route {...this.props} render={(props) => (
            FakeServer.isUserAuthenticated() == true
                ? <Component {...props} />
                : <Redirect to='/login' />
        )} />
    )
}

}

/*
mapStateToProps
Function to relate reducer results with props:
 */
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state.userReducer.user,
    loading: state.userReducer.loading
});

/*
mapDispatchToProps
Function to map dispatcher trigger functions as pros:
 */
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
        getUserByUsername : (username) => {dispatch(userActions.getUserByUsername(username))}
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PrivateRouteComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on what @AnshulBansal said in the comments, you are declaring `renderView` as a function but you're using `this.props` as a function parameter and that's wrong.

```
let renderView = (this.props) => ( 
                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're defining the parameter of the function to be the value of a property of your class (this is my best explanation for this, I know it's not the best)

Looking at what `renderView` does, it seems you don't really need any parameters for the function:

```js
let renderView = () => ( 
  FakeServer.isUserAuthenticated() == true 
    ? <Component {...this.props} />
    : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )
```

If you need the function to have a parameter, you should do something like:

```js
let renderView = (props) => {
  // do something
}
// ...
renderView(this.props)
```

Alternatively, you can also have default parameters

```js
let renderView = (props = this.props) => {
  // do something
}
```